# How do I make a button make a form in another form?

Tags: c#, operating-system

So in my current situation I have my Desktop form set to open things inside that form through the MDI.Container.

I have a form automatically open when the Desktop form is started. After reading that form you would click "next" on the form button and it SHOULD open the new form in the same mdi container, but instead it opens it in a new window in my actual OS. I want it to open in the original MDI container in the Desktop form.
If you can help me out please do!

I've tried the following:

```
this.IsMdiContainer = true;
Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
welcome.MdiParent = this;
welcome.Show();
```

Comment: if you are using `MDI` you should read up and understand the following `Parent` and `Owner`

Answer (score 0):

Would this help? I'm not sure to get your question

```
// C#
protected void MDIChildNew_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 newMDIChild = new Form2();
    // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
    newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;
   // Display the new form.
   newMDIChild.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you make the form ismdicontainer = true inside code you should make form ismdicontainer true while designing, not in run time.